# What could be the most efficient algorithm to find index in an array that matches given conditions?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arrays

I have an array A with n elements. I am trying to write an efficient algorithm to find the index of elements that matches condition A[j-1]>=A[j]<=A[j+1].

Example:

```
A = [12,11,9,7,5,54,67,87,23,54,20,22]
```

Should return `4` because subarray `[7,5,54]` matches the condition where `A[4] = 5.`

Below is the solution I tried. It has run time `O(n)`. I am looking if there is any other better solution?

```
 def sol_1():
      for j in range(1,n):
        if A[j-1]>=A[j] and A[j]<=A[j+1]:
          return j
      return False
```

Comment: what about the indexes $1$ and $n$. What is the satisfying conditions for them?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect there might be a "better" solution? And what do you mean with "better"?

Comment: You say "Should return `4`" but then you actually only return `True` or `None`. Which one is it?

Comment: Before efficiency, I suggest you first make it correct. For example for `n = 3` `A = [1,2,1]` your code *crashes*.

Comment: `Should return 4` What about `10`, `8`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do better than $n-2$ in the worst case. You can show this using an adversarial argument.

Suppose the array is $A = [1,2,3,\dotsc,n]$. There is no index in the array that satisfies that $A[i-1] \geq A[i] \leq A[i+1]$. Therefore, the answer is trivially no.
For the sake of contradiction assume that there is an algorithm that solves the problem in less than $n-2$ operations. It means there is an index of the array that is not accessed by the algorithm. Suppose this index is $t$ and $1<t<n$. Since the algorithm has not seen this index yet, the adversary can decrease $A[t]$ value by $1$, i.e., $A[t] = t-1$. Now, index $t$ satisfies that $A[t-1] \geq A[t] \leq A[t+1]$; thus proving the algorithm wrong.

Therefore, any correct algorithm must access at least $n-2$ entries of the array. Therefore, the lower bound on the running time is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been trying if it can be solved in a better way using the divide and conquer approach. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: What do you mean by better? Less time complexity?

Comment: Yes, anything less than O(n).

Comment: @five_star_021 That is what I proved. It is not possible to do better in the worst case.